# Binding a WPF Listbox to Xml in Button_Click event?

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, listbox

I am trying to bind a ListBox to Xml in Button_Click event in xaml.cs.
my Xml is simple

```
     <books>
        <book>ABC/book>
        <book>XYZ</book> 
    </books>
```

Here's what I am doing..

in xaml.cs

> ```
>       XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
>         x.LoadXml(e.Result.ToString());
>         listbox1.ItemsSource = x;
> ```

and Xaml is

> ```
>     <ListBox x:Name="lstbxTrends" Margin="95,112,8,18" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Books}">
>         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
>             <DataTemplate>
>                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Book}" />
>             </DataTemplate>
>         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
>     </ListBox>
> ```

But nothing shows up in Listbox..?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the ItemsSource in code, you need to set the DataContext:

```
listbox1.DataContext = x;
```

The DataContext is what the ItemsSource binding is trying to resolve against (since you have specified no other Source, RelativeSource or ElementName in the Binding).